# what is web to lead and web to case in Salesforce?

Tags: web2lead, web2case

I was going through visual workflow in Salesforce I found Web to Lead and web to Case Here's [link](http://www.buttonclickadmin.com/salesforce-visual-workflow-getting-started/). Can anyone please explain What is Web to Lead and Web to Case in Salesforce ? I got only got very vague  understanding of these cause I am new to Salesforce. What is Lead and Case here refers to? What is Use case of these two ? I tried to understand Lead but it wasn't explained very clearly here's [link](https://ap1.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_leads_cheatsheet.pdf).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both Web to Lead and Web to Case generate basic HTML to pass onto your website developer that would pass queries straight into Salesforce.

Web to Lead is normally Sale driven, e.g. someone interested in a product or receiving a call back from a Sales person.

Web to Case is normally Customer Service driven, e.g. My product doesn't work help me please.

Both are basic enquiry forms. You have a daily limit of how many can be created - this is to prevent spammers taking over. A word on that, mask the org id on the web page - as this is all they need to spam using the POST function.

One thing I found is that web 2 lead create failures (e.g. not passing a validation rule) email a system administrator, web 2 case does not.

Both offer a quick and basic way to get a public facing page up to get data straight into Salesforce and use the automation that it can provide.

Comment: What does lead refer to in Web2Lead?Can you please explian what is lead in Salesforce?

Comment: In a pure salesforce definition a lead is someone who has expressed an interest in something of yours but hasn't yet been qualified/turned into opportunity.

Answer (score 2):

Lead is a prospect for an opportunity. I will explain with an example, say I am a salesperson met a customer and understood his requirements. With the conversation I can figure out whether he is interested to purchase the product. If yes, then if he is interested to purchase product with my organisation. If any of the answers are positive then this is positive lead, means it can turn to opportunity.

Comment: What does this answer have to do with `Web To Lead` or `Web To Case`?